# How to vertically align paragraph inside div

Tags: html, css

http://www.gabrielleelizabethstudios.com/GEA_html/thejustingallery.html

I'm having trouble getting this to vertically align automatically. I know I can add a padding-bottom to center it manually, but I'd rather it position vertically automatically. How would I go about doing this? And I need to keep the display: inline-block functionality.

```
<div style="width:375px; height 250px; display: inline-block; margin:10px; padding: 0;text-align: center;">          
                <p>title</br></br>     
            text for paragraph goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Also have a look at: [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set `vertical-align: middle;` to `.masonry .item {` class

```
.masonry .item {
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

and add `vertical-align: middle;`  to parent div of the `p` element

```
<div style="width: 375px; display: inline-block; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, would have never have guessed to do that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -8):

You could use a CSS class for your paragraph tags, something like this:

```
.p {
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

Comment: This is not a scalable solution. Padding-left works for other stuff but not vertical aligning.